# no value being returned from program

Tags: python, tkinter, return, return-value

I have the following code:

```
import time
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import external
import excelwork

window = Tk()
window.title('My Sample Solution')
window.geometry('700x500')
window.configure(background = 'green')
rows = 0
while rows < 50:
    window.rowconfigure(rows, weight = 1)
    window.columnconfigure(rows, weight = 1)
    rows += 1
found = ['']

#Label Input:
Label(window, text='Search For: ').grid(column = 0, row = 0)
#Dropdown select search
def DisplayDevNum():
    search_for = Srch.get()
    found = excelwork.srch_knums(int(search_for))
    #This is where you choose what to do with the information
    return found

def DisplayDevAdd():
    search_for = Srch.get()
    found = excelwork.srch_add(str(search_for))
    #This is where you choose what to do with the information
    return found

def DisplayDevCty():
    search_for = Srch.get()
    found = excelwork.srch_cty(str(search_for))
    #This is where you choose what to do with the information
    return found

def DisplayDevStt():
    search_for = Srch.get()
    found = excelwork.srch_stt(str(search_for))
    #This is where you choose what to do with the information
    return found

def DisplayStrNum():
    search_for = Srch.get()
    found = excelwork.srch_snums(int(search_for))
    #This is where you choose what to do with the information
    return found

def DisplayStrName():
    search_for = Srch.get()
    found = excelwork.srch_stnm(str(search_for))
    #This is where you choose what to do with the information
    return found


def chng_srch():
    srch_choices.get()
    if srch_choices == options[0]:
        DisplayDevNum()
        return found()
    if srch_choices == options[1]:
        DisplayDevAdd()
        return found()
    if srch_choices == options[2]:
        DisplayDevCty()
        return found()
    if srch_choices == options[3]:
        DisplayDevStt()
        return found()
    if srch_choices == options[4]:
        DisplayStrNum()
        return found()
    if srch_choices == options[5]:
        DisplayStrName()
        return found()

options = ['Device Number','Device Address','Device City','Device State','Store Number','Store Name']

srch_choices = ttk.Combobox(window, values = options)
srch_choices.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

#Input Entry
Srch = Entry(window)
Srch.grid(column = 2, row = 0)



display_tabs = ttk.Notebook(window)
display_tabs.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 50, rowspan = 47, sticky = 'NESW')
tab1 = ttk.Frame(display_tabs)
display_tabs.add(tab1, text = 'Info')

Label(tab1, text = 'Kiosk ID: ').grid(column = 0, row = 0)
Label(tab1, text = found[0]).grid(column = 1, row = 0)


#Go Button
Button(window, text = 'Go', command = chng_srch).grid(column = 3, row = 0)



window.mainloop()
```

I am trying to print the value of my functions as results of a search. However, I am not getting any output from my returns. My excelwork import is a personally written file and that works. I have tested it and it returns the values expected when directly run. That said, I'm not entirely sure where I went wrong. Can somebody help?

Comment: Could you post the part of the code where you are trying to print?

Comment: Label(tab1, text = found[0]).grid(column = 1, row = 2)

Comment: ***"not getting any output from my returns"***: You can't return anything to a `command=...`. Read up on [Tkinter.Label.config-method - option `text=`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few separate issues with your current code.

First, simply changing the `found` variable will not update the `Label`. You can instead make a Tkinter `StringVar` to hold the text you want to display, which will cause the `Label` to be updated whenever it changes. See the Patterns section of the `Label` [docs](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) for an example of this.

The second issue, is that when you run the `DisplayDevNum` function, you need to save the output - running the function by itself doesn't actually do anything. So instead of doing

```
if srch_choices == options[0]:
        DisplayDevNum()
        return found()
```

you need to do something like this:

```
if srch_choices == options[0]:
        return DisplayDevNum()
```

However, simply returning a value from `chng_srch` will not update either `found` or the Label contents. To change the `found` variable (assuming that `found` is now a `StringVar` used by the `Label`), you don't need to return anything from your functions, but you do need to [mark `found` as a global variable](https://pythonprogramming.net/global-local-variables/) (note that many people consider global variables bad practice in most situations). Another option would be to keep the `Label` as a variable, and have the `chng_srch` function explicitly update the `Label` contents.

Comment: You can't return anything to a `command=...`, rethink your answer.

Comment: While I definitely should have been clearer, I wasn't trying to say that the command needs to return a value. I was trying to explain why the way `return` was used was not working. The function launched by the button will of course need to explicitly update the label or use a global variable.